# ajax script is not posting any values

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to run a ajax script which works as a livesearch, but the script is not even posting any values that i am inserting.

Do anyone knows where i am making the mistake. Please desperately need some help to solve this issue.

Html --

```
        <form method="post" id="searchform">
            <input type="text" size="30">
            <div id="livesearch"></div>
        </form>
```

Script --

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".contents-value").keyup(function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var data = {};
    data['livesearch'] = el.value;    
    var url = '/home';

    // Submit data via AJAX§
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'post',
        data : data,
        success: function (data) {   

    }
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot in advanced .

Comment: Open developers console and see what's going on.

Comment: @u_mulder i have checked it and there is not post value, when i insert any data

Comment: What is it - `change('livesearch'`? Shouldn't it be `change(function() {}`?

Comment: Where is contents-value() defined ?

Comment: @AndresZapata in this line ` $(".contents-value").on('livesearch', function(e) { `

Comment: @ChristoferHansen calling `contents-value()` in your onkeyup of the input[type='text']. Where is that function defined? (note: `$(".contents-value").on('livesearch', function(e) {` is not defining it)

Comment: @Terminus can u kindly give me a suggestion how should i define it

Comment: @ChristoferHansen, check my answer :)

Comment: you shouldn't have to define it. remove that `onkeyup='...'` bit entirely. Do you have a livesearch plugin for jQuery that adds lets you use that `.on('livesearch',...`?

Comment: @Terminus i do not have any livesearch plugin for jQuery

Comment: than change `.on('livesearch',...` to `.on('keyup',...`. And, remove the `onkeyup='...'` from the input[type=text]

Comment: i have update the question which i am trying to according to your and @Anders comments, can you kindly have a look

Comment: what gets returned from the php script? What is actually in the php script? Do you know about the developer console and the network tab which let's you see what is sent and  what is received from xhr (ajax) requests?

Comment: @Terminus yes i am using firebug to see if there is any data is posted or not, but it is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91923/discussion-between-terminus-and-christofer-hansen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with this.

1. You're declaring a keyup event inside the input element, which invokes function with name contents-value(). Which is not defined in your code.
2. You're sending the data wrong, in "el" var, you getting the input (That's fine). But in this line:

   ```
   data['livesearch'] = e.valueOf().val;

   e.valueOf().val is undefined.
   ```

Instead do this:

```
   data['livesearch'] = el.value;
```

Finally, change the on event to keyup:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".contents-value").keyup(function(e) {
        var el = e.target;
        var data = {};
        data['livesearch'] = el.value;    
        var url = '/home';

        // Submit data via AJAX§
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: 'post',
            data : data,
            success: function (data) {   

        }
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
```

Comment: @Anders thanks a lot for your correcting me, but it is still not working, because it is still not posting any values when i inser something on the textbox

Comment: @ChristoferHansen How's your backend set up ? Also, try doing the following in your ajax call:
success: function (data) {   
    console.log(data);
        }

Tell me how it goes